# Как отправить canvas на сервер javascript?

Tags: javascript

Здравствуйте делаю ресайз в  canvas, как его отправить на сервер

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Получить картинку из канваса можно так:

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
```

Теперь можете отправить ее на сервер, например, через ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'APIurl',
    data: image,
    dataType: 'image/png',
    async: true,
    success: function (success) {
    }
});
```